# custom controls added as OSGI plugin appear twice

Tags: xpages

I added a couple of custom control into a plugin and imported them on the server using the update site. They are working quit well so far but when i open an application in the designer client i can see the custom control from the plugin twice.

I tried to add them the same way bootstrap4xpages is adding a plugin but mine is duplicated.

One entry is without any icon the other has the standard grey cc icon. Not the end of the world but i must have done something wrong. Any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue with 9.0 and 9.0.1, specific to components that are Custom Controls. I encountered it quite a while ago. Mark Leusink had the same problem for Debug Toolbar and discussed it with the IBM developers at IBM Connect last year. So I would hope it will be addressed in the next point release, 9.0.2.

It still works fine though, regardless of which one you select.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Yes they do work find it just doesnt look nice. Is there a workaround or something to avoid it?

Comment: Not that I know of. When I hit the problem, it displayed once in 8.5.3 but twice in 9.0. So I suspect it's something to do with the Controls palette rather than code in the plugin. My feeling is that the when upgrading to 9.0.2, a fix will mean it will suddenly only display one entry.